# Awaiting an IAsyncOperation in F#

Tags: f#, windows-store-apps, async-await, iasyncoperation

I have the following code in F#:

```
   let CreateSampleDataFromJson<'T>(path) = 
      let uri = new Uri(path)
      async {
         let file = StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri)
         let jsonText = FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file)
         return JsonObject<'T>.Parse(jsonText)
      }
```

The problem I'm having is that `file` is an `IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>` and not a `StorageFile` as `ReadTextAsync` expects.

In C# you can do something similar to this:

```cs
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri)
```

i.e.

```cs
public async Task<T> CreateSampleDataFromUrl<T>(string path)
{
  var uri = new Uri(path);
  var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
  var jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
  return JsonObject<T>.Parse(jsonText);
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to await an `IAsyncOperation` in F#.  The usual `let!` doesn't work.  i.e. the following fails to compile:

```
async {
   let! file = StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri)
```

With the compiler error:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    Async<'a>    but here has type    IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>
```

I found a document that said there's an `AsTask()` extension method defined in the `System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions` class which I can use as follows:

```
 let! file = StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).AsTask() |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Is there a standard way of doing this or something available in an F# library somewhere that makes this a bit nicer?

Comment: Looks like `AsTask()` is ok, as WinRT has its own async model based on `IAsyncOperation`.

Comment: Excuse me, how did you use StorageFile in F#. I have tried to open Windows.Storage in F# portable libraries (profile 7 and 47), but can not do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems fine by me. If you're looking for a nicer syntax, how about rolling it into a function like this (without the possibly gratuitous type annotations):

```
let await<'a> (op: IAsyncOperation<'a>) : Async<'a> =
   op.AsTask() |> Async.AwaitTask
```

This will give you the almost exact same syntax you'd see in c#:

```
async {
   let! file = await <| StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri)
   ...
}
```

The compiler errors you were getting with your previous approaches are to be expected. All async workflow cares about is the F#-specific Async type. This type gives you a way to interop with the rest of .NET world through Tasks, but that's it. IAsyncOperation is from a 'different part of the world', I wouldn't expect F# core libraries to support it anytime soon.

Comment: I like it.  The <| operator makes it read really nicely. I keep forgetting that's available